# Incremental Decision Tree in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification

Can anyone recommend a decision tree classifier implementation, in Matlab, that can be used incrementally?

I have found class classregtree, but I couldn't find special argument for incremental situation.

Answer (score 0):

CHAID is a type of decision tree technique, based upon adjusted significance testing (Bonferroni testing).

Check this out:

```
t = classregtree(X,y)
```

Creates a decision tree t for predicting the response y as a function of the predictors in the columns of X. X is an n-by-m matrix of predictor values. If y is a vector of n response values, classregtree performs regression. If y is a categorical variable, character array, or cell array of strings, classregtree performs classification. Either way, t is a binary tree where each branching node is split based on the values of a column of X. NaN values in X or y are taken to be missing values. Observations with all missing values for X or missing values for y are not used in the fit. Observations with some missing values for X are used to find splits on variables for which these observations have valid values.

```
t = classregtree(X,y,'Name',value)
```

Specifies one or more optional parameter name/value pairs. Specify Name in single quotes. The following options are available:

Comment: I have found this before, but It has not any options for incremental learning(online learning).